# How do i add orders from woocommerce to different tabs from different site of woocommerce in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

[![i have tried adding getsheetsbyname("")it still dint work][2]][2]

i have tried adding getsheetsbyname("")it still dint work

Comment: Should it be `JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)`?

Comment: I have tried that too but doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can change the names of the sheets to whatever you wish..

[image]

Comment: Thank you.So how will the code know to which tab should it save?This is my first tiem doing,quite unsure how

Comment: In this example it will save the data in the sheet names listed in the shts array.  You can put whatever sheet names you wish.

Comment: I see okay..so if different tab has different codes i have to create different files then run them?

Comment: I don't understand you last comment.  A script is in a project which has access to all sheets.  appendRow() appends a row to the bottom of a sheet

Comment: so i have order from different countries and i added the sheet names.So order from sg goes to sg tab and order from thai goes to thai tab but mine currently does not get saved.

Comment: I did not understand what it is that you wanted.  Perhaps you can begin by pasting you code into the the question so that it can be copied.  We don't like images of code.   Then we need a little better explanation of what you want.   Perhaps some examples might be inorder.

Comment: [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: if (currency == 'SGD')
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sg');
  else if (currency == 'MYR')
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('msia');
  else //if (currency == 'THB')  if (currency == 'SGD')
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sg');
  else if (currency == 'MYR')
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('msia');
  else //if (currency == 'THB')
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('thai');
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('thai');

This is how i solved it